# Issue while reading excel column names by using GetOleDbSchemaTable

Tags: .net, excel, c#-3.0

After some google searching I found out how to read excel column names [How To Retrieve Schema Information by Using GetOleDbSchemaTable and Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309488)
. Though the sample is in VB.Net, I am using C#.net.
My code is :

```
public DataSet ReadXslToDataset(string fileName,string sheetName)
            {
                ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="+fileName+";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";
                using (objConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                        objConn.Open();

                        String[] restrection = { null, null, sheetName, null };
                        dtColumnNames = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable  (OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, restrection);
                        string strColumnName = string.Empty;
                        if (dtColumnNames != null)

                          strColumnName = dtColumnNames.Rows[0]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();

                }
}
```

But I am finding that  the column field is blank and henceforth getting the exception

**There is no row at position 0.**

The excel file looks as

```
S.No    Issue
1      log4net message pattern not displayed properly in the log file
2      Reading blank rows from Excel while populating into dataset
```

and I have ensured that I am passing the right file & sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no row at position 0.

Try

```
if (dtColumnNames != null) {
   if(dtColumnNames.Rows.Count > 0){
      strColumnName = ColumnNames.Rows[0]["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString
    }
  }
```

Sorry I may have the syntax slightly out  - I'm more of a VB.net guy.